# what city was unix invented in?

Tags: technology, computers

Unix operating system (and the C language) was developed at Bell Labs by Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie in 1970. What city did they invent it in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unix was developed at the Murray Hill, New Jersey laboratory of Bell Labs. See article in The Economist for June 10, 2004.

Comment: Nice. I found the article: http://www.economist.com/node/2724348 I wasn't sure which Bell Labs location